# Autocomplete of non-global functions

Tags: front-end, customization, contexts, autocomplete

In *Mathematica* 9 and 10 they added [autocompletion](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/UsingTheInputAssistant.html). Out of the box this works great, but when I set the `CellContext` to `"Notebook"` instead of the default `"Global"` (following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4896011/mathematica-separating-notebooks)) it no longer autocompletes the functions I define in my notebook.

If I specify that the function is global, then the autocomplete mechanism works as you can see in the example below:

[image]

Is there a way of making *Mathematica's* autocompletion work with functions just defined within the notebook, and not just with global functions?

Comment: I guess explicitly typing ``Notebook`My`` is not an option? :-)

Comment: @halirutan:  In principle that does work, but it is in no way ideal. I would have to find the context and type e.g. Notebook$$21$423901`My, and the context would change every time I would close and reopen the notebook.